# Printing a list in dataframe format

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list

I am trying to print a two-dimensional list in pandas data frame format.

The result of printing the data as Pandas Data frame

[Pandas Data Frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QhHg.png)

My Code

```py
cols = ["prod_id", "description", "cost"]

data = [["p01", "Domaxx Geniune Leather RFID Blocking Trifold Wallets-Made Genuine Soft Leather Large Classic Pocket Wallet,Holding 9 Cards Photo ID Coin Pocket and 2 Note compartments-Black Surface/Orange Inner", "10.00"],
["p02","Neck Wallet, Passport Holder with RFID Blocking Anti-Theft Travel Pouch Security Wallet for Credit Cards and Passport - Silver","15.00"]]

temp_str = ''

for item in cols :

    temp_str += "\t " + item

print(temp_str)

i = 0

for row in data :

    print(str(i) + "\t" + row[0] + "\t" + row[1] + "\t" + row[2])
    i += 1
```

============

## Print Result

[normal List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umb0B.png)

Comment: Please use proper formatting else it is hard to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understood your input, but if you want this:

```
  prod_id                                        description   cost
0     p01  Domaxx Geniune Leather RFID Blocking Trifold W...  10.00
1     p02  Neck Wallet, Passport Holder with RFID Blockin...  15.00
```

from:

```
cols = ["prod_id", "description", "cost"]
data = [["p01", "Domaxx Geniune Leather RFID Blocking Trifold Wallets-Made Genuine Soft Leather Large Classic Pocket Wallet,Holding 9 Cards Photo ID Coin Pocket and 2 Note compartments-Black Surface/Orange Inner", "10.00"], ["p02","Neck Wallet, Passport Holder with RFID Blocking Anti-Theft Travel Pouch Security Wallet for Credit Cards and Passport - Silver","15.00"]]
```

Just do this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)
```

### EDIT

I show you an example with shorter columns fields:

```
data = [["p01", "Domaxx Geniune Leather RFID Blocking Trifold Wallets-Made", "10.00"],
["p02","Neck Wallet, Passport Holder with RFID Blocking Anti-Theft Travel Pouch Security Wallet f","15.00"]]


fmt = '{:<4}{:<10}{:<100}{}'
data1 = map(list, zip(*data))

print(fmt.format('', "prod_id", "description", "cost")) # your columns here
for i, (x, y, z) in enumerate(zip(data1[0], data1[1], data1[2])):
    print(fmt.format(i, x, y, z))
```

You can play with the values of the format to reach the result that is the best for you

Comment: Hi Joe, Thanks for responding back. We don't have privileges to install pandas at my current work location. We need to do it with plain python itslef.

Comment: @Santosh I've edited, please check if it gives the result you expected

Comment: Thanks Joe. This is much better than I was earlier.